# Origine des sens différents de « à nouveau » et « de nouveau »

Tags: expressions, sens, étymologie, synonymes

Comme tout un chacun, j'ai appris que « **à nouveau** » implique une manière *différente* d'accomplir, une nouvelle fois, une action :

> J'ai joué un morceau de piano, j'ai été sifflé, j'ai essayé à nouveau.

« **De nouveau** » implique une manière *identique* de refaire une action :

> J'ai joué un morceau de piano, il a tellement plu que l'on m'a demandé de le jouer de nouveau.

Quelle est l'origine de cette différence de sens?

Même Littré n'est pas clair, pour une fois, et définit les deux expressions par le neutre « de rechef » (*sic*, dans mon édition de 1873 et non corrigé dans les rééditions récentes).

Comment: En fait *à nouveau* n'implique pas forcément une manière différente, il peut aussi être utilisé comme synonyme de *de nouveau*. Mais c'est vrai qu'il y a des cas où on utilisera plutôt *à nouveau*.

Comment: @Gilles: Si je voudrais m'en enquérir, alors faudra-t-il afficher à/de nouveau :) une question ? Je penche pour une révision de l'OP ici pour l'approfondir histoire d'obvier à deux questions autour d'un sujet.

Comment: @LePressentiment Cette question se concentre sur l'histoire. Si tu veux approfondir l'usage contemporain, je pense que ça mériterait une nouvelle question.

Answer (score 3):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) signale l'apparition de la locution adverbiale ***de nouveau*** (*de nuvel*) en 1121-1134,

> « d'abord avec le sens  de « récemment, depuis peu » qui a disparu,
>   puis avec la valeur moderne de « une fois de plus » (1160).   La
>   locution  ***à nouveau***  (1135) est d'abord employée spécialement
>   comme terme de banque au sens de « sur un nouveau compte » et se
>   distingue de *de nouveau* en ce qu'elle signifie « une fois de plus,
>   mais avec une façon différente » (1852). Cependant cette nuance n'est
>   pas toujours sentie par le locuteur, qui lui donne souvent le sens
>   « d'une fois de plus » (1884).