# Quand « comme » est-il suivi d'un article, défini ou indéfini ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

Dans cet extrait :

> La locution *à nouveau* (1135) est d'abord employée spécialement **comme terme de banque** au sens de « sur un nouveau compte » et se distingue de *de nouveau* en ce qu'elle signifie « une fois de plus, mais avec une façon différente » (1852).
>
> <sub>[Source](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7792/1995)</sub>

pourquoi *comme* est-il utilisé seul ? Pourrait-on faire ressortir les points communs et les divergences entre « *comme* », « *comme* + l'article défini » et « *comme* + l'article indéfini » ?

Comment: Cette fois il y a une une autre question qui traite exactement du cas de la préposition *comme* (pour celle-là, la présence ou non d'un article a une grande répercution sur le sens du complément).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Dans l'exemple ci-dessus, (différemment à la réponse que tu cites en référence) la présence de l'article indéfini ne change pas le sens de la phrase dans la mesure où l'explication ne permet pas d'ambiguïté.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Par ailleurs la question de LePressentiment portait sur la possibilité de mettre un article défini dans l'exemple qu'il cite. Non, on ne pourrait pas mettre d'article défini, il faudrait pour cela définir l'objet (avant ou après). Ceci est indépendant de la préposition comme, par exemple, [« Cet objet, connue sous la référence 2003UB313, a été identifié comme l'objet le plus éloigné en orbite autour du soleil »](http://www.le-systeme-solaire.net/eris.html)

Comment: Pour moi il s'agit exactement de la même distinction. *Comme **un** terme de banque* est tout à fait possible, avec un sens différent (qui rendrait cette phrase particulière sans queue ni tête, mais ce n'est pas le problème).

Comment: Ah ici il s'agit d'un attribut du sujet (pas de l'objet) mais ça ne change rien, la réponse de Circeus est toujours valide, elle inclut aussi ce cas.