# Différence entre « à nouveau » et « de nouveau » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, usage, prépositions

Lors de la rédaction d'un document de maintenance, que devons-nous utiliser comme syntaxe : « votre matériel est **de nouveau** opérationnel » ou
« votre matériel est **à nouveau** opérationnel » ?

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7791/origine-des-sens-differents-de-a-nouveau-et-de-nouveau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je suis d'accord avec *Un francophone* mais je vais rajouter quelques petites nuances et exemples extraits de [www.francaisfacile.com](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-8389.php).

De nouveau marque en effet la répétition mais il peut aussi être utilisé pour exprimer la *nouveauté* ou *de la même façon* :

- Je ne vois pas ce que cet argument apporte **de nouveau**! => comme *nouveauté*.
- J'ai raté ce dessin, je vais le faire **de nouveau** = *de la même façon*, donc il sera encore raté.

Mais

- J'ai raté ce dessin, je vais le faire **à nouveau** => *d'une nouvelle manière* et donc il aura plus de chances d'être réussi.

Il y a également l'exemple trivial du pluriel :

- Je me suis fait **de nouveaux amis**. => *des amis nouveaux*.

Comment: thanks, pas facile d'exprimer cette distinction. Combien de personnes vont là cerner.???

Answer (score 6):

*De nouveau* signifie *encore une fois* et marque donc la répétion.

*À nouveau* par contre a deux sens, le premier est *comme si c'était la première fois* et marque alors un recommencement sur de nouvelles bases plutôt qu'une répétition, et le second *encore une fois* (et dans ce sens est donc synonyme de *de nouveau*).

Dans ce contexte les deux sont possibles sans changer le sens.  Dans d'autres, substituer l'un a l'autre peut changer le sens, ou du moins l'impression laissée.

Answer (score 0):

Je privilégierai « de nouveau » qui implique le retour à un état identique alors qu' « à nouveau » peut signifier que le matériel est bien opérationnel, mais différemment.

Cette nuance tend cependant à disparaître.